# Angular UI Sortable not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am working on Angular UI for making my menus sortable, sometimes the code works and sometimes its breaks like duplicating the entries or filling the blank menus when I am re arranging items.

Following is the full code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Sortable Demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

        myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
        });

        //angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <div ng:repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
    .item, .placeholder {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #EEE;
}

.placeholder {
    background: #AEF;
}

</style>
```

Also If someone could help me while creating this in `JSFiddle` as I tried this but unable to set it as a fiddle - [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k2cb2/)

**EDIT-**

This is how it becomes at times [Screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ca33yu1ab) (Menu Items duplicated)

Comment: You need to check up typo ng-repeat, ng-model, ...

Comment: @JungryulChoi No it works even with the `:`

Comment: check this for a "fiddle": http://plnkr.co/edit/nAMngvPX4vZWP0dqFZND?p=preview no changes made though, not sure what's wrong yet.

Comment: You need to add ng-app in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2cb2/10/

Comment: @ChrisPreston Try re arranging "six" element multiple times you can see that it breaks

Comment: @Akhlesh check this screen shot its breaking thr too http://awesomescreenshot.com/0de33z0k14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Working Fine.... Take a look at this

**[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/gw5fp/embedded/result/)**

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gw5fp/)**

[image]

**html**

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <div ng:repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

Comment: I tried yours fiddle too but it breaks http://jsbin.com/figisage/1  & screenshot - http://awesomescreenshot.com/02233yzle4

Comment: its working fine within jsbin, then how come..... here break means what, is it means when you applied that in your application, is the screen short given is part of that

Comment: No its from your jsBin..just try drag drop "six" element up, down etc and you will see in your demo too that few items either duplicated or removed.

Comment: yeah its working but I guess you replaced the library..I am looking for this library because I am using the same at multiple places :)

Comment: Yeah sure..was still searching to make it working with my current version

Answer (score 7):

I wrote my own directive ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/dO764KziaLCv1uixORzG?p=preview)):

```
<ol dnd-list="wrap.names">
    <li ng-repeat="name in wrap.names">{{name}} is {{$index}}</li>
</ol>


// directive for a single list
app.directive('dndList', function() {
     return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        // variables used for dnd
        var toUpdate;
        var startIndex = -1;

        // watch the model, so we always know what element
        // is at a specific position
        scope.$watch(attrs.dndList, function(value) {
            toUpdate = value;
        },true);

        // use jquery to make the element sortable (dnd). This is called
        // when the element is rendered
        $(element[0]).sortable({
            items:'li',
            start:function (event, ui) {
                // on start we define where the item is dragged from
                startIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
            },
            stop:function (event, ui) {
                // on stop we determine the new index of the
                // item and store it there
                var newIndex = ($(ui.item).index());
                var toMove = toUpdate[startIndex];
                toUpdate.splice(startIndex,1);
                toUpdate.splice(newIndex,0,toMove);

                // we move items in the array, if we want
                // to trigger an update in angular use $apply()
                // since we're outside angulars lifecycle
                scope.$apply(scope.model);
            },
            axis:'y'
        })
    }
});
```