# cannot use angular ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I downloaded the latest source code from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable. However I cannot use it. I opened the demo.html but it was broken.

**Updated:**
When I open demo.html in the console :

```
Navigated to https://www.google.com.au/search?q=if+demo+break+angular-ui+sortable&oq=if+…-ui+sortable&aqs=chrome..69i57.18815j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8
Navigated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624807/angular-ui-sortable-not-working-properly
ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingCachedScripts//Ad_2_49_3_0/ebStdBannerEx.js:82 Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.
Navigated to https://www.google.com.au/search?q=if+demo+break+angular-ui+sortable&oq=if+…-ui+sortable&aqs=chrome..69i57.18815j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8
Navigated to file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/web/plugins/ui-sortable-src0.13.4/demo/demo.html
```

Here are the files I included

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script src="js/third-party/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/keypress.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/ng-upload.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/ui-calendar.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/date.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>              
        <script src="js/third-party/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/third-party/bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui-sortable-src0.13.4/src/sortable.js"></script>
```

my app

```
angular.module('app.ReportCtrl',['ui.sortable']).controller('ReportCtrl', function($http, $rootScope, $scope)
```

and elements

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="selectedColumns">
        <li ng-repeat="col in selectedColumns">{{col.displayName}}</li>
</ul>
```

when I am not using ui-sortable the list can be displayed
but when using ui-sortable the list wouldn't display.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the reason is the angular version no match.